# Не читается файл построчно c++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, ввод, ifstream

Пишу программку для генерации паролей. Функция check проверяет существует ли уже такая запись, если существует, то её не надо записывать в файл. Но она все время возвращает false(Даже если записывается все время один и тот же символ). Я пробежался отладчиком и как выяснилось даже в цикл while не заходит.

```
std::string str;
std::string strInput;
std::ifstream inf("pass.txt");
std::ofstream fout("pass.txt");

int count_line = 0;
int povtor = 0;

char buff[62] = {'A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

bool check(std::string str) { // проверка на существование записи
    
    while (getline(inf, strInput)) { 
        std::cout << strInput << std::endl; 
        if (strInput == str) {
            povtor++;
            
            return true;
        }
         
    }

     
    
    return false;

}

void BruteForce(int str_long) {

    for (;;) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < str_long; i++) 
        {
            str += buff[rand() % 62 + 0];       
        }

        if (!check(str))
        {
        fout << str << std::endl;
        count_line++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        std::cout << "Слово записано: " << str << "\nКол-во слов: " << count_line << "\nКол-во повторившихся: " << povtor << "\n";
        str.clear();
        system("cls");
        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1)) {
            fout.close();
            inf.close();
            break;
        }

    }

    
}

int main()
{    
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    BruteForce(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

После первого же вызова `check` вы закрываете файл, и все ваши попытки чтения — из закрытого файла. Естественно, ничего не читается, ничего не сравнивается, и возвращается `false`.

Надеюсь, вопроса "и как это исправить?" не будет, и вы подумаете и решите эту проблему самостоятельно.

**Update**
Ну что ж, надежды не оправдались...

Вариант 1. С открытием файла в каждом вызове `check`.

```
ofstream fout("pass.txt");

int count_line = 0;
int povtor = 0;

char buff[62] = {'A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

bool check(const string& str) { // проверка на существование записи
    ifstream inf("pass.txt");
    string strInput;
    while (getline(inf, strInput)) { 
        cout << strInput << std::endl;
        if (strInput == str) {
            povtor++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void BruteForce(int str_long) {
    for (;;) {
        string str;
        for (int i = 0; i < str_long; i++)
        {
            str += buff[rand() % 62 + 0];
        }
        if (!check(str))
        {
            fout << str << endl;
            count_line++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        cout << "Слово записано: " << str << "\nКол-во слов: " << count_line << "\nКол-во повторившихся: " << povtor << "\n";
        getchar();
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    BruteForce(1);
}
```

Вариант 2. **С перемоткой**. Обратите внимание на то, как идут строки `ifstream` и `ofstream`, и подумайте, почему это важно (подсказка: что будет, если файла еще нет?)

```
ofstream fout("pass.txt");
ifstream inf("pass.txt");

int count_line = 0;
int povtor = 0;

char buff[62] = {'A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

bool check(const string& str) { // проверка на существование записи
    string strInput;
    inf.clear();
    inf.seekg(0);
    while (getline(inf, strInput)) { 
        cout << strInput << std::endl;
        if (strInput == str) {
            povtor++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Остальное — как и в варианте 1.

Да, заодно исправил еще несколько ошибок. Там сами смотрите, что и почему. С клавиатурой — не ошибка, мне для отладки проще останов после каждой строки.

P.S. А вообще, все это совсем не так делается. Особенно перебор всех возможных вариантов строки...

Comment: ,В данном примере я согласен, что сглупил и закрывал файл. Просто были мысли может быть из за не закрытого фала могут происходить какие ошибки. Но разве при чтении файла (getline(inf, strInput)) он сам не открывается? Сколько примеров не смотрел там никто файл отдельной строкой не открывает. И все же, проблема так же, он не заходит в цикл.

Comment: Нет, конечно. Не открывается. Далее — при попытке чтения из закрытого файла `getline` возвращает `false` (точнее, ее возврат приводится к `false`) и в цикл не заходит — скажите, много раз будет заход в цикл `while()false){}`?

Comment: Ну я убрал закрытие файла и все равно не работает

Comment: А вы перематываете его на начало? :) Вот вы дочитали его до конца... а потом? Стоит указатель позиции чтения на самом конце, и на любую попытку чтения кричит — нет, достигнут конец файла, читать нечего!...

Comment: А можно ваш пример пожалуйста? Я просто читаю бред который вы пишите и просто понять не могу. Нигде в Интеренте про перемотку позиции не написано, но вы явно лучше знаете

Comment: Отчего ж нет — не глядя на ваше хамство... О перемотке — поищите в Интернете функцию-член `fstream` под названием `seekg`.